# Styrofoam/foamular under pavers

Tags: pavers

I am looking to build paver patio to put pool on it. I will be using 12ftx24ftx52 inch intex ultra pool. My hoa doesn't allow permanent above ground pools and that's why I have to remove it after summer. I don't want concrete slab as I don't like the look. My intent is to use standard 4x8 pavers which I already have on my patio

It seems standard pavers panels don't have strength needed for pool
Did anyone use foamular under pavers? Any issue with that? Anything more than drilling drain holes to adjust?
Thanks

Comment: What sort of pool.  I could try guessing above ground one, but we need more information.  Type of pool, size, capacity, why you would want to put pavers under it.  With polystyrene in them I dont see how they can have more compressive strength than concrete pavers.

Comment: I'm assuming you're talking about an above-ground pool of some kind.  A pool is a lot of water, i.e. a lot of weight.  Those paver panels seem to be hit or miss with people.  You'll probably get some settlement, which may or may not be a problem.  Any reason you don't want a *concrete* patio?

Comment: I will be using 12ftx24ftx52 inch intex ultra pool. My hoa doesn't allow permanent above ground pools and that's why I have to remove it after summer. I don't want concrete slab as I don't like the look. My intent is to use standard 4x8 pavers on the foam board (I already have pavers on other site of my patio and want to match them)

Comment: The best information is going to come from the manufacturer of the pool you intend to place there.

Comment: Plain concrete slab will probably look out of place, but these days they can make it look almost like anything(for extra money).  Making it look/match your pavers should not be too hard.  That is a lot of water weight and you do want the base to hold up.